# How cancel akka stream within play framework conroller

Tags: playframework, akka-stream

I have a stream, that should be controlled from http api(start,stop, only one instance). Response should be streamed to client. Here code with play framework controller:

```
  class Processor{

    def job(): Source[Int, NotUsed] ={
      stop()
      Source(Stream.from(1)).delay(1.second, DelayOverflowStrategy.backpressure)
    }

    def stop(): Unit ={
      //TODO
    }
  }

  class MyController(process: Processor) {

    def startJob = Action {
      val source = process.job()
      Ok.chunked(source)
    }

    def cancell = Action {
      process.cancel()
      Ok("canceled")
    }
  }
```

I need ability to cancel job. When client closes connection, job should not cancel - it's just like log output. I read about `KillSwitches`, but dont understund how use it with play controller, that accepts `Source`. Any helps?

I think I need some output source, different from Job source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implement my task with `Monix` `Observable`. By action, I can run, cancel and connect to running stream. Anyway, I interested in akka-stream solution in educational purposes. Here monix solution:

```
class StreamService(implicit ec: Scheduler) {

  private val runningStream: AtomicAny[Option[RunningStream]] = AtomicAny(None)

  def run(): Option[Source[ByteString, NotUsed]] =
    runningStream.get match {
      case None =>
        val observable = Observable
          .interval(1.seconds)
          .map(_.toString)
          .doOnTerminate(cb => runningStream.set(None))
          .doOnSubscriptionCancel(() => runningStream.set(None))
          .publish

        val cancelable_ = observable.connect()

        this.runningStream.set(Some(RunningStream(cancelable_, observable)))
        connect()
      case _ => None
    }

  def connect(): Option[Source[ByteString, NotUsed]] =
    runningStream.get
      .map(rs => rs.observable.toReactivePublisher)
      .map(publisher => Source.fromPublisher(publisher).map(ByteString(_)))

  def cancel(): Unit =
    runningStream.get.foreach(_.cancelable.cancel())

}

object StreamService {
  case class RunningStream(cancelable: Cancelable, observable: ConnectableObservable[String])
}


class SomeController @Inject()(streamService: StreamService, cc: ControllerComponents)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def run() = Action {
    val source = streamService.run().getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("Stream already running"))
    Ok.chunked(source)
  }

  def connect() = Action {
    val source = streamService.connect().getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("Stream not running"))
    Ok.chunked(source)
  }

  def cancel() = Action {
    streamService.cancel()
    Ok("ok")
  }
}
```